# macro help to find LastRow IF

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro to set `LastRow` by finding last empty row in column B.  However, sometimes the entire row is empty, except for Row 1 where the headers are.
I need to set an IF statement on the `LastRow` variable to say IF Range B2 is NULL (or equals 0), then use B2 as parameter, to set `LastRow`. Else, find last row by `.End(xlUp)`

I've already tried different IF statements on my variable but all leads to an error message

```
Sub WeeklyGL()

  'Set Variable Parameters for Monthly Sheet
     Dim mySheet As String
     Dim LastrowMonth As Integer
     Dim mKey As Range
     Dim mKeyrng As Range
     Dim mValrng As Range

     mySheet = Sheets("Weekly_GL").Range("AE1")
     LastrowMonth = Sheets(mySheet).Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row --> this is where i need help
     Set mKey = Sheets(mySheet).Range("AC1")
     Set mKeyrng = Sheets(mySheet).Range("AC2:AC" & LastrowMonth)
     Set mValrng = Sheets(mySheet).Range("AD2:AD" & LastrowMonth)
```

Last try:

```
LastrowMonth = If Sheets(mySheet).Range("B2") ISNULL Then .Range("B2") Else Sheets(mySheet).Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: keep your code and add `If LastrowMonth = 1 Then LastrowMonth = 2`

Answer (score 1):

I've clean your code a bit with worksheet reference:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    'Set Variable Parameters for Monthly Sheet
     'Dim mySheet As String 'instead of this, create a worksheet variable like this:
    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    Dim LastrowMonth As Integer
    Dim mKey As Range
    Dim mKeyrng As Range
    Dim mValrng As Range

    Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weekly_GL").Range("AE1")) 'this way you can reference and work cleaner:
    With mySheet
        LastrowMonth = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'this is the standard to find the last row
        If LastrowMonth = 1 Then LastrowMonth = 2 'this is what you were looking for
        Set mKey = .Range("AC1")
        Set mKeyrng = .Range("AC2:AC" & LastrowMonth)
        Set mValrng = .Range("AD2:AD" & LastrowMonth)
    End With

End Sub
```

`Option Explicit` is a good choice to avoid errors because it force you to declare all your variables.

Using `With` allows you to reference what you are using, in this case `mySheet` just by using `.`

Comment: hi- thanks for the cleanup. i plugged in the new code, but i am getting an error message: run-time error 13- 'Type mismatch'. when i debug, it highlights the line: Set mysheet = thisworkbook.Sheets.....

Comment: Try now @Mancho and make sure there is a sheet name on that  range.